# Why isn't this transform scale animating?

Tags: css, debugging, animation, transform, gsap

I am trying to animate a `circle` from `scale(0)` to `scale(1)` but it does not animate even though `opacity` animates.

https://codepen.io/labeeb/pen/rJaNdN

```js
setInterval(function() {
  TweenMax.to($("circle"), 1, {
    css: {
      opacity: 1
    },
    scale: 1
  });
}, 1000);
```

```css
circle {
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="500">
    <g>
        <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="50" fill red></circle>
    </g>

</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

I edited your post and put the code into a code-snippet.

While doing that, the error `TweenMax is not defined` was visible in the console.

1. You really did not define TweenMax.
2. You forgot to add some code.